mgcv::gam mimicry of default geom_smooth gam when n is small
Am performing mgcv::gam over each unique XY pairing (2 in this instance) and both of these pairings have just 11 obs. Ideally, the prediction of A=0 should be somewhere between B = 2,000 and 1,000. Understandably, the model is predicting A=0 at B= ~450. I have explored alteration of k, spline type, and in the past have looked at shape constrained additive models (slow processing over larger datasets and invalid when certain assumptions are not met). Ideally, mgcv::gam would behave similar to geom_smooth gam in ggplot for my purposes here, however, it is understood that synthetic obs are created for plotting purposes in geom_smooth gam as opposed to the original data (see stack overflow link below). Without creating artificial/synthetic data, how would I best be able to approximate the geom_smooth fit? Am open to other model types, spline functions, etc, however, monotonicity/direct relationships are not guaranteed for the expanded form of this DF. I will be performing this over several more pairings (so weighting could vary if that approach is taken) so ideally, the solution would be compact and work with summarise and be flexible to work with several other pairings. More weighting as A approaches 0 could be useful in all instances though.
stat_smooth gam not the same as gam {mgcv}
# packages
library(sf)
library(reshape2)
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
library(data.table)
library(stringr)
library(zoo)
library(ggplot2)
library(mgcv)
library(scam)
library(npreg)
library(cgam)
library(dtplyr)
library(collapse)
library(lubridate)
library(purrr)

# reading in data
DF <- structure(list(X = c(1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 3, 3, 
3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3), Y = c(2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 
2, 2, 2, 2, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4), grp = c("0", 
"1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "10", "11", "0", 
"1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "10", "11"), A = c(6.1513671875, 
4.8748779296875, 3.40283203125, 1.9866943359375, 1.1297607421875, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 6.0810546875, 4.8055419921875, 3.33447265625, 
1.9195556640625, 1.065185546875, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), B = c(10000, 
7500, 5000, 3000, 2000, 1000, 800, 600, 400, 200, 100, 50, 10000, 
7500, 5000, 3000, 2000, 1000, 800, 600, 400, 200, 100, 50)), row.names = c(NA, 
-24L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))

# running model over XY pairings
DF_dat <- DF %>% 
  summarise(gam_model=list(gam(B~s(A,bs="cs",fx=TRUE,k=6))), .by = c(X,Y))

# predicting B for A = 0
pred_df <- data.frame(A=0)
gam_predict <- function(m) predict(m,pred_df)
DF_dat$gam_pred_0 <- sapply(DF_dat$gam_model,gam_predict)


EDIT: In fact a spline function that simply connects the points over these groups in a similar fashion would likely be more ideal. no model may actually be required if the points are connected in some piecewise fashion. splinefun theoretically would be the solution as it is supposed to connect through the data points, but, it does not appear to be doing that

models <- DF %>% 
  summarise(spline_fun=list(splinefun(A, B)), .by = c(X,Y))

models$spline_pred_0 <- sapply(models$spline_fun, function(x) x(0))



What does "it is understood that synthetic obs are created for plotting purposes in geom_smooth gam" mean? I really don't understand what the issue is. The predictions from the models look fine (although I wouldn't set fx=TRUE). They are close to DF %>% filter(A == 0) %>% summarise(meanB = mean(B), .by = c(X,Y)). Why do you expect different?

hello. I was just noting from the provided link that "n controls the size of the dataset for the newdata argument in predict and therefore stat_smooth doesn't use the original dataset when making the predictions". I understand why the GAM fits at 450, but, if spline_fun connects through the points and the first zero on both samples occurs roughly between 1000, and 2000, that is where I would expect the line to connect prior to 450. plot this data and fit with the default geom_smooth(method="gam", formula = y~s(x), fullrange=TRUE) and you will see the fit line indeed lands in this region.

If you want to create a curve, you have to predict with new data. I plotted the data and a curve with the predictions and it looked perfect. I don’t see any issue to solve here.

the question was flawed with respect to the anticipated outcome...a couple of solutions would be to remove the 0's and fit the essentially curvilinear spline function and see where 0 lands (assuming general monotonicity), and/or keep the first appearance of 0 with decreasing A and B and fit a GAM.
